# Return an object from typeahead package in meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, typeahead.js

I've added atmospherejs.com/package/typeahead to a meteor project and it's working fine. It's returning a string but can I change typeahead to return an object and have the template render the object accordingly? I need the _id in addition to the name from the participant I'm adding to a mongodb-collection.

js-file:

```
Template.raceAddParticipant.acparticipants = function () {
  return Participants.find().fetch().map(function (post) { return post.name; });
};
```

html-file:

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" data-source="acparticipants" name="name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Participant" />
```

regards
Claus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeahead is not designed for Meteor and you will need to do a lot of wrangling to work with the strings it returns.

One solution is to use something like https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete, which works of Meteor Collections instead of arrays, is reactive, and supports rendering using Meteor templates with proper data contexts (i.e. `_id` and all other fields). It's basically like typeahead, but designed around Meteor.

Comment: I've added autocomplete and it's working fine. How will I include the participant._id in the html-file? Right now I have the name in inputAutocomplete.

Comment: The template that renders each item shows additional information like club, _id etc. But how do I get _id to {{> inputAutocomplete}} so I can save it to a new collection? This works. {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="name" name="name" placeholder="Participant" placeholder="Name" }}

Comment: I'm setting a session variable via the callback: function() but not shure if there is a better approach. The participants name, club, _id etc. can be seen by the Template event handler via Session.get() where I'm saving the participant using 'submit form':.

Comment: @kometen I don't exactly understand your question.

Comment: Pardon, it's somewhat unclear. https://github.com/kometen/karusselrenn/blob/master/client/views/races/race_add_participant.html, line 5 has inputAutocomplete for the name. Template acParticipants renders the available options. How to include year, club, _id to inputAutocomplete? In https://github.com/kometen/karusselrenn/blob/master/client/views/races/race_add_participant.js I'm setting club and _id as session variables on line 45-46. It's unclear for me how to include a participant object to the input-form.

Comment: Maybe use an `<input type="hidden">` which is updated from the Session variables?

Comment: Tried {{> inputAutocomplete settings=settings id="club" name="club" type="hidden" }} and <input type="hidden" id="club" name="club" /> just below inputAutocomplete for the name. But it did not include club to the form. I'll stick with the "callback: function (doc) Session.set('currentUserClub', doc.club); Session.set('currentUserId', doc._id);
}"

Comment: I meant that you should use the hidden input just below the autocomplete, and update its value using the callback. I'm not sure why the input itself isn't being serialized, that's another question altogether.